# How to use Bean Validation 2.0 (JSR 380) features in Tomcat 8?

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, bean-validation

Bean Validation 2.0 (JSR 380) should be able to perform the following validation:

```
@Valid
public class MyBean{
  private List<@NotNull String> members;
}
```

But it seems to just ignore the @NotNull annotation. Also, `@NotBlank` and `@NotEmpty` annotations are ignored.

I have the Bean Validation 2.0 API and reference implementation in my class path via Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.15.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I use Java 8 and Tomcat 8 with Jersey.

Do I need to configure `Tomcat` somehow to use the 2.0 implementation and not the default one that is bundled in JDK 8 (Like enabling `Optional<>` support in `Jackson`)?

Comment: Please also add the code where you expect validation to happen. While Tomcat is a servlet container only, I consider validation API is generally expected to be used integrated with Java EE technology: Take a look at the [integration chapter of the validator documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-integration)

Comment: Thanks @Selaron , your suggestion took me to https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html, which is the component that is responsible for Bean Validation in Jersey. That led me to solution I'll detail bellow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause of the issue was that the Bean Validation extension for Jersey brings an older version of Hibernate validator implicitly, while the Hibernate validator I explicitly requested in the pom.xml is not used.

To solve it, I excluded the hibernate validator that Jersey pulls implicitly:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
 </dependency>
```

add my version of Bean Validation

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.15.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

and added Java EL:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1-b09</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried to add @Valid annotation to your class/field where validation should be performed ?

From my experience for some reason this annotation has to be present to make validation be executed.

Comment: Yes. it did not help. I'll add it to the question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are missing the `EL` implementation, try adding this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1-b09</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks @Matteo Baldi, Java EL was indeed missing.